# What is the other way to do a request with a promise? with nodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, promise, ibm-watson, alexa-skills-kit

Hello I want to connect my watson assisstant with an alexa device, for this I need Amazon development skill kit and AWS lambda. But i can't connect watson because i got problem with my promises and i can't see the logs of my code in the amazon developer console. And my assistant work on nodeJs application.

There is some codes that i tried :

```
const MyNameIsIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
      && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'SearchIntent';
  },
   async handle(handlerInput) {


      assistant.createSession({
        assistant_id: assistant_id
      })
          .then(res => {
              session_id = res.session_id;
          })
          .catch(err => {
              console.log(err);
          });
        assistant.message({
            assistant_id: assistant_id,
            session_id: session_id,
            input: {
                'message_type': 'text',
                'text': "hello"
            }
        })
            .then(res => {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2));
                 speechText = res.output.generic.response.text;
            })
            .catch(err => {
              speechText = err;
      });


    }, function(err){
      speechText = "Problem with Api call";
    });

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speechText)
      .getResponse();
  },
};
```

And other way with promise:

```
try{

      let res = await assistant.createSession({
        assistant_id: assistant_id
      });

      session_id = res.session_id;

      let message = await assistant.message({
        assistant_id: assistant_id,
        session_id: session_id,
        input: {
          'message_type': 'text',
          'text': "hello"
        }

      });
      speechText = message.output.generic.response.text;

    }catch(err){
      speechText = err;
    }
```

The results of speechText should give me "Good day to you" it's a response that comes from Watson.but now Alexa says "Sorry, I can't understand the command. Please say again."

Do you have an others ways to try this with other way to do a promise? thanks you!

Comment: This example only has `text` property inside `input`, https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk/blob/2581acd4c7a9c70b0d76e214cf587f9b3430664e/examples/assistant.v1.js.

Comment: Even this test case as well: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk/blob/71a0714a0429a60f8b92546d677d346c51fcef7a/test/integration/assistant.v2.test.js#L45

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts for consideration ...

Looking at the first attempt, what you have in `handle()` is two independent promise chains, efectively like this:

```
async handle(handlerInput) {
    doSomething_1().then(...).catch(...);
    doSomething_2().then(...).catch(...);
},
```

What you appear to need is to perform the two async operations in series:

```
handle(handlerInput) {
    return doSomething_1().then(doSomething_2)....;
},
```

In full (with some guesswork/inventiveness):

```
handle(handlerInput) {
    return assistant.createSession({ assistant_id })
    .then(res => {
        return assistant.message({
            'assistant_id': assistant_id, // ??
            'session_id': res.session_id,
            'input': {
                'message_type': 'text',
                'text': 'hello'
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            err.message = 'Problem with assistant.message() call';
            throw err; // send error with custom message down the down the error path.
        }
    }, err => {
        err.message = 'Problem with assistant.createSession() call';
        throw err; // send error with custom message down the down the error path.
    }
    .then(res => res.output.generic.response.text) // send res.output.generic.response.text down the success path.
    .catch(err => err.message) // catch error from anywhere above and send err.message down the success path to appear as `speechText` below.
    .then(speechText => { // `speechText` is the text delivered by the immediately preceeding .then() or .catch()
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
        .speak(speechText)
        .getResponse();
    })
    .catch(err => { // in case handlerInput.responseBuilder.speak().getResponse() throws
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Notes:

1. text is passed down the promise chain's success path and appears as `speechText` in the final `.then()`; no need for an outer variable.
2. custom error messages (if required) are injected with intermediate catches, which modify and (importantly) rethrow their errors.
3. a third intermediate catch intercepts the error path and sends err.message down the success path.
4. consumption of `speechText` is necessarily dependent on the sequence `assistant.message().then(assistant.message)` having completed.
5. code could be written with async/await but would difffer only in semantics; both versions would exploit promises.

The code is not necessarily a working solution, but should help in the understanding of the kind of data/error flow required by this application.

Good luck with it.